# AWS Cognito User pool federated signIn

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, facebook-login

I create a Cognito user pool and set signup ,sign in signup process with facebook, Google and Cognito user pool. when i signup using Facebook or Goole create account successfully. but when login  there is a error which is below

> The user is not authenticate

How can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue with creating federation identity pool and set my user pool id and client id on it. then my issue was fix